# Remove errors in clgpustress C++ GPU stress code

Tags: c++, gpu, stress-testing

I opened the C++ code from [clgpustress](https://github.com/matszpk/clgpustress) in Visual Studio 2010 but it shows many errors, as seen in the following image:

[image: errors]

How to add the libraries? Or is there another C++ gpu stress code?

Comment: press build to get the actual compiler output, and copy/paste the actual errors into your question.  Screenshots aren't searchable.

Answer (score 1):

I am author of the clgpustress.

clgpustress requires the popt library which provides the command line 
parsing.

Unfortunatelly, popt is not too much portable and it is compilable under
Unix/Linux systems. I created on the github special version of a popt library
here: https://github.com/matszpk/popt-msvc.

This version was created to be compilable under MSVC and Windows.
Download that version and try to compile and link with clgpustress.

CLgpustress is an OpenCL application, so it requires the OpenCL runtimes and development libraries which can be found in AMDAPP package.